# OSX Catalina - GCC/PIP compilation issue

Tags: python, gcc, g++, macos-catalina

I'm trying to install a tool on my computer via pip on my Mac and have been having issues.

I've seen suggestions on StackOveflow to install the Command Line Tools, to run variants of `xcode-select --install`, and export `CPATH` and `CPATH`. This resolved the header error. I'm now getting the error

```
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and

```
    psutil/_psutil_osx.c:36:43: fatal error: CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h: No such file or directory
     #include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
                                               ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Has anyone come across anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem after updating to Catalina macOS 10.15 and installing xcode 12 beta 6. My golang code failed compiling with error

```
share/go/src/crypto/x509/root_cgo_darwin.go:16:10: fatal error: 'CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h' file not found
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
```

Tried `xcode-select --install`, and other suggestions, none worked.

The final [fix I found](https://medium.com/@croath/catalina-macos-10-15-%E4%B8%8B-cgo-%E4%B8%8D%E8%83%BD%E8%BF%90%E8%A1%8C%E7%9A%84%E8%A7%A3%E5%86%B3%E6%96%B9%E6%A1%88-5b580140b45a) was to manually link directories that were messed up by the update.

Steps

1: turn off rootless/System Integrity Protection on Mac: Disable SIPe

This setup is needed to make change to system configuration.
reboot your mac and hold-on `command` + `R` to enter recovery mode.
Once in Recovery mode, open a Terminal window from the Utilities drop-down menu at the top of the screen. Type the following into the Terminal window:

```
csrutil disable
```

2: reboot into normal mode

3: open terminal, make the root folder writable

```
sudo mount -uw
```

4: fix the links

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework
ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers Headers
ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Modules Modules
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework
ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers Headers
ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Modules Modules
```